# What is the correct way to handle multiple requestCodes in onActivityResult()?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two activities and the second activity should send back a string of text to the appropriate textview on activity 1 depending on if I select button 1 or button 2.  I believe my intent in launchFoodActivity() in activity 1 is incorrectly asking for 2 requests at the same time.  How can I correct my code to have each string of text be sent to the appropriate textview in activity 1?

Activity 1

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView mReplyTextView1;
private TextView mReplyTextView2;
public static final int TEXT_REQUEST = 1;
public static final int TEXT_REQUEST2 = 2;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mReplyTextView1 = findViewById(R.id.food_text_1);
    mReplyTextView2 = findViewById(R.id.food_text_2);

}

public void launchFoodActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FoodListActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TEXT_REQUEST);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, FoodListActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent2, TEXT_REQUEST2);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String textFoodReply1 = data.getStringExtra(FoodListActivity.EXTRA_REPLY);
                    mReplyTextView1.setText(textFoodReply1);
                    break;
                }
            }

        case 2:
            if (requestCode == 2) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String textFoodReply2 = data.getStringExtra(FoodListActivity.EXTRA_REPLY);
                    mReplyTextView2.setText(textFoodReply2);
                    break;
            }
         }
    }
}
}
```

Activity 2

```
public class FoodListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_REPLY = "com.dev20.shoppinglist.extra.REPLY";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_list);

}

public void returnFoodItem1(View view) {
    String replyItem1 = getResources().getString(R.string.cheese_text);
    Intent replyIntent = new Intent();
    replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY, replyItem1);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, replyIntent);
    finish();
}

public void returnFoodItem2(View view) {
    String replyItem2 = getResources().getString(R.string.apples_text);
    Intent replyIntent2 = new Intent();
    replyIntent2.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY, replyItem2);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, replyIntent2);
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what this code is supposed to do, so by extension I don't know how to fix it. Can you help me?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov The buttons on activity 2 are supposed to send a string of text to the textviews in activity 1.  For example: Button 1 on activity 2 should send the string "cheese" to the first textview in activity 1.  Button 2 on activity 2 should send the string "apples" to the second textview on activity 1.

Comment: Whatever is the activity 1 here... I think I see what is happening here. Your main problem is your `FoodList` has no way of communicating where the result goes. Since `FoodList` has no control over `RequestCode`, it should put something in response extras. For example, put in a field index along with `EXTRA_REPLY`.

Comment: I see, I just added an extra - EXTRA_REPLY to store that value separately.  Now in activity 1 (mainActivity) should i use two different startActivityForResults in two separate methods to retrieve the data?

Comment: No, right now you built your code in such way that main activity has no input for what food list does. Whatever button user clicks will dictate what result main activity fill receive.

Comment: `launchFoodActivity` should be simplified; there is no need for 2 different `Intent`s or 2 different request codes.

Comment: In `onActivityResult` you don't need to use the `requestCode`, as there is only 1 in use. Use the `resultCode` for the decision logic.

Comment: Use 2 different `resultCode`s to refer to the 2 different `TextView`s.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thank you for your help, after what you said and codebod I have it all working

Comment: @codebed thank you, got it working!